# Teams Bot download attachment file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to dev a Teams app to get the attachment of a message (from a channel, conversation, personal) and send it to a web service somewhere else.

From a message extension action, I can get the following data.

This is from the activity.

```
{
  commandId: 'CustomForm',
  commandContext: 'message',
  requestId: 'cf6747b9-bb94-4a70-87d1-d89834e33757',
  messagePayload: {
    linkToMessage: 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:a841a46f-80f6-41cd-8717-7e41d6817195_af24b8a2-cfe8-453a-a9b4-4a917b1534ae@unq.gbl.spaces/1663342621107?context=%7B%22contextType%22:%22chat%22%7D',
    id: '1663342621107',
    replyToId: null,
    createdDateTime: '2022-09-16T15:37:01.107Z',
    lastModifiedDateTime: null,
    deleted: false,
    subject: null,
    summary: null,
    importance: 'normal',
    locale: 'en-us',
    body: {
      contentType: 'html',
      content: '<p>test attach pdf</p><attachment id="0b922164-a59f-44bc-8a4d-a94ad77bf94c"></attachment>'
    },
    from: {
      device: null,
      conversation: null,
      user: [Object],
      application: null
    },
    reactions: [],
    mentions: [],
    attachments: [ [Object] ]
  },
  context: { theme: 'default' }
}
```

This is the content of attachments

```
{
  id: '0b922164-a59f-44bc-8a4d-a94ad77bf94c',
  contentType: 'reference',
  contentUrl: 'https://xxwdq-my.sharepoint.com/personal/thehuy_xxwdq_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Microsoft Teams Chat Files/PDF.PDF',
  content: null,
  name: 'PDF.PDF',
  thumbnailUrl: null
}
```

I have an ID and the contentUrl.
ContentUrl is not working because I'm accessing the file without the user credentials.

I found out online, the best way to access files is to use the MS Graph.
I tried to use it in Postman, but I don't find out what endpoint to use and what parameter is what ?

Can somebody help me figure this out ?

Thanks.

Comment: Download the contents of the primary stream (file) of a driveItem. Only driveItems with the file property can be downloaded.
Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: How does your bot get the attachment from the user? You should be able to save the file to a temp location before sending it to another web service.

Comment: It's possible if the message comes fron the compose box. I have access to the dowloadUrl in that case. In my case, the message comes from message extension. So I have only the contentURL.

Comment: I looked into the `driveItem` concept the other person mentioned, and it looks like one way to accomplish this might be to take the OneDrive share path that you have (part of the `contentUrl`) and use it to create a sharing link which you can then request permissions for and convert to a sharing token you can use to access the content, all through REST calls.

Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http